# Angular and lazy loading: menu in a component, router-outer in other

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

In my Angular app I have in main component a list of menu button, which opens several lazy loaded component. The code of the page is

```
<button routerLink="/lazy-loaded-page">page</button>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And the code of the routing file is

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'directory', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/directory/directory.module').then(m => m.DirectoryModule) },
```

The code works correctly; now, I want move the buttons menu in a header dedicated component. But the router outlet should stay in the main page. How can I, from a selection in a page x, load the component in an other router-outlet in the page y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an header component with your menu, then in app.component.html:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Sometimes we thing that simple thing should be very complicated!